# Can Objects not on display-list access root or any object that is added on displaylist?

Tags: actionscript-3, list

Suppose in document class

```
public class Test extends MovieClip
{
    public function Test()
    {
        var object1:ClassA = new ClassA();
        //addChild(object1);
        object1.accessRoot();
    }
}

public class A extends MovieClip
{
    public function accessRoot()
    {
        var mc : MovieClip = root as MovieClip;
        mc.box.visible    =  false;
    }
}
```

Now box is placed at stage. but when Class A is added to Test Class, it works and when object of Class A is not added in Test constructor, root becomes in-accessible. Is there any way that objects not on display-list can access root or display-list objects??

Comment: What is 'root' in your case? Is it a MainTimeline object or the default class object (like [object Main])? How are you wanting to use 'root'?

Comment: in my case, it is a MainTimeline or it can be default class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend having your classes fiddle around with root or stage, it's way better to dispatch events and have the proper encapsulation.

Hacky way:

```
public class A extends MovieClip
{
    private var _root:MovieClip;        

    public function A(root:MovieClip)
    {
        _root = root;
    }

    public function accessRoot()
    {
        _root.box.visible = false;
    }
}
```

Proper way:

```
public class A extends MovieClip
{

    public static const ACCESS_ROOT:String = "access_root";

    public function accessRoot()
    {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(ACCESS_ROOT));
    }
}

// in your document class

var myA:A = new A();
myA.addEventListener(A.ACCESS_ROOT, handleAccessRoot);

public function handleAccessRoot(e:Event):void{
    box.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: In hacky way, Passing root reference violates Encapsulation?? what is the disadvantage of hacky way?

Comment: when your object access the root level they are fiddling around with things they normally should not have access to, meaning they can reach all kinds of things. it doesn't really have any direct disadvantages other than enabling you to do unsuitable things.

Comment: handleAccessRoot is never triggred.. did i need to implement an interface to ProperClass

Answer (score 0):

I normally create a sort of base class that holds a reference to the document class - or **"main"** class. Anything that I create from here that should need reference to anything defined in Main would extend Element. Example:

The Main class (or document class):

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function Main()
    {
        var obj:MyElement = new MyElement();
        obj.main = this;
        // stage will be outputted
    }
}
```

Element - which stores reference to the main class.
It also contains an `init()` function which I generally use in place of a constructor by overriding it.

```
public class Element extends MovieClip
{
    private var _main:Test;

    public function set main(m:Main):void
    {
        _main = m;
        init();
    }

    /**
     * Called when _main is defined
     */
    protected function init():void
    {
        // override me
    }

    public function get main():Main{ return _main; }
}
```

And here's how you would use Element as a base class for your classes:

```
public class ClassA extends Element
{
    /**
     * Override init rather than using a constructor
     */
    override protected function init():void
    {
        trace(main.stage);
    }
}
```

The only thing really to note is that you of course have to set the _main property whenever you create an object. (as shown on line 9 of Main).